# Hadoop: implement interfaces from o.a.h.mapred, or extend classes from o.a.h.mapreduce?

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I'm learning Hadoop (0.20.205) and I'm a little bit confused.  Which way is recommended:

A) Implement `Mapper` and `Reducer` interfaces from `org.apache.hadoop.mapred`, and configure the job using `JobConf`, as in the `PiEstimator` example.

B) Extend `Mapper` and `Reducer` classes from `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce`, and configure the job using `Job`, as in the `WordCount` example.

Which one is more likely to become obsolete in the future?

Hbase (0.90.4) seems to prefer the second way, since `TableOutputFormat` in `o.a.h.h.mapred` is deprecated, and `TableOutFormat` in `o.a.h.h.mapreduce` is not.  On the other hand, useful classes like `IdentityMapper` or `IdentityReducer` seem to exist only in `o.a.h.mapred`.  Overall, I'm leaning towards version B.

Which way would you choose, and why?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it better to use the mapred or the mapreduce package to create a Hadoop Job?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598422/is-it-better-to-use-the-mapred-or-the-mapreduce-package-to-create-a-hadoop-job)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

o.a.h.mapred is the old MR API and the o.a.h.mapreduce is the new API. There is not much difference functionality wise, but the new API is easier to maintain. Please see my response in StackOverflow [here](http://goo.gl/qGH4J).

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Also, now I see my question is a duplicate.