# Writing data to MySQL from Hadoop Reducer

Tags: mysql, hadoop

I am experimenting with Hadoop Map-Reduce and in my tests I am able to store output of reducers to HBase. However, I want to write data a mysql database instead of HBase. Mappers would still be reading their input data from HBase. I have found this but it requires to use MySQL at both input and output while I need it at only output. Also, above [link](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2009/03/database-access-with-hadoop/) uses some deprecated classes from org.apache.hadoop.mapred package for which a new package org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce is available now, however I am not able to find any tutorial using this new package till now.

Answer (score 1):

> I have found this but it requires to use MySQL at both input and output while I need it at only output.

The InputFormat (DBInputFormat) is independent of the OutputFormat (DBOutputFormat). It should be possible be possible to read from HBase in the Mapper and write to a DB in the Reducer.

With the new MR API set the Job#setInputFormat and Job#setOutputFormat, with the old MR API set the JobConf#setInputFormat and JobConf#setOutputFormat appropriately to what input/output format is required. Both these formats need not be same. It should be possible to read from an XML in a mapper and write to a Queue in the Reducer also if required.

> Also, above link uses some deprecated classes from org.apache.hadoop.mapred package for which a new package org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce is available now, however I am not able to find any tutorial using this new package till now.

If you are comfortable with the old API, then go ahead and use it. There is [not much difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598422/is-it-better-to-use-the-mapred-or-the-mapreduce-package-to-create-a-hadoop-job/7600339#7600339) in the functionality between the new and the old API. There are two DBInputFormat for the old and the new API. Make sure you don't mix the old/new InputFormats with the old/new MR API.

Here is a [tutorial](http://sonerbalkir.blogspot.com/2010/01/new-hadoop-api-020x.html) on the new API.

Comment: I also thought the same and used new API for this. However, I am getting NPE at some point in DBConfiguration class. So, I am seeking for appropriate uses of DBInputFormat, DBConfiguration and DBOutputFormat.

Comment: Thanks for your last link. I found my problem by going through comments on that [tutorial](http://sonerbalkir.blogspot.com/2010/01/new-hadoop-api-020x.html). My problem resolved with reply for first comment of author in that tutorial.