# Why is TableOutputForma deprecated?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I'm using hbase 0.94.1
I wish to do a MapReduce Job
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapred.TableOutputFormat is deprecated, but without any explanation.

Does someone know why? What should I use instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not - it's moved from the package org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapred to org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.

There's some discussion here: [Is it better to use the mapred or the mapreduce package to create a Hadoop Job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598422/is-it-better-to-use-the-mapred-or-the-mapreduce-package-to-create-a-hadoop-job)