# JobConf v/s Configuration for Hadoop 1.0.4

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Hi I am new to Hadoop and it's FileSystem. I saw two different examples of WordCount using `JobConf` and `Configuration`. What is difference in them.

I studied that `JobConf` was part of old package `org.apache.hadoop.mapred`(that deprecated in 0.20.x) but Configuration is part of new package `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce`. But now in v1.0.4 it is un-deprecated.

Currently we have  two ways to run map reduce jobs in java, one is by using (extending) classes in `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce` package and other is by implementing classes in `org.apache.hadoop.mapred` package.

I want to know:

1. What is difference between `mapred` and `mapreduce` package structure and why `mapred` is un-deprecated?
2. Which approach is better for v1.0.4 to use and why? `JobConf` or `Configuration`?
3. Which is better for v1.0.4? `mapred` or `mapreduce` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it better to use the mapred or the mapreduce package to create a Hadoop Job?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598422/is-it-better-to-use-the-mapred-or-the-mapreduce-package-to-create-a-hadoop-job)

Comment: I have read that answer. That approach was for v0.20 and v0.21/22 . But here I am asking about v1.0.4 . Please don't connect it with that. And don't make any decision before understanding completely.

Comment: 1.0 is nothing else than the version between 0.20 and 0.22. See it as a polished 20.x version. You should search for existing answers before adding a new question, not to mention the research of the version numbering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look in [the releases page](http://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html), you can see that 1.0.4 corresponds to something around 0.20.20x

To give some context, here is what was being discussed [on the mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/mapreduce-dev@hadoop.apache.org/msg01833.html):

```
The "old" MapReduce API in org.apache.hadoop.mapred was deprecated in the 0.20 
release series when the "new" (Context Objects) MapReduce API was added in
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce. Unfortunately, the new API was not complete in 0.20
and most users stayed with the old API. This has led to the confusing situation 
where the old API is generally recommended, even though it is deprecated.
```

So as you can see, it's mainly a matter of retro-compatibility.

So the bottom line is, if you are starting your application now with 1.0.4 you **should** use `mapreduce` and not `mapred` since it's the preferred way now, but you **can** still use the old `mapred` if you have legacy applications. Which implies you **should** use `Configuration`.

As for the difference between `mapred` and `mapreduce`, as explained in the extract above it mainly comes from the introduction of `Context` objects, but there are a bunch of other changes and new classes that are not available in the old `mapred`.