# hadoop.mapred vs hadoop.mapreduce?

Tags: apache, hadoop, mapreduce

Why are there two separate packages map-reduce package in Apache's hadoop package tree:

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapred
```

http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/hadoop/hadoop-1.0.3/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce
```

http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/hadoop/hadoop-1.0.3/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/

Why are they separated out? Is there documentation that clarifies this?

Comment: some more references [mapred or mapreduce][1] to help mapred api vs mapreduce


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598422/is-it-better-to-use-the-mapred-or-the-mapreduce-package-to-create-a-hadoop-job/7600339#7600339

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598422/is-it-better-to-use-the-mapred-or-the-mapreduce-package-to-create-a-hadoop-job

Answer (score 66, accepted):

They are separated out because both of these packages represent 2 different APIs. `org.apache.hadoop.mapred` is the older API and `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce` is the new one. And it was done to allow programmers write MapReduce jobs in a more convenient, easier and sophisticated fashion. You might find this [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/sh1mmer/upgrading-to-the-new-map-reduce-api) useful, which talks about the differences in detail.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: If I have the option for something things between mapred and mapreduce, but some only have the option for mapred, should I use mapred everywhere?

Comment: Note that the the old api was un-deprecated and might even be recommended, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598422/is-it-better-to-use-the-mapred-or-the-mapreduce-package-to-create-a-hadoop-job