# JobControl and JofConf.setMapperClass() error

Tags: java, generics, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to use `JobControl` to connect multiple Mappers and Reducers together but encounter the following error when invoking `JobConf.setMapperClass`:

```
setMapperClass(java.lang.Class<? extends org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper>) in
    org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf cannot be applied to
    (java.lang.Class<capture#530 of ? extends org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper>)
```

It seems that java complains my implementation of Mapper, which is based on `mapreduce.Mapper`, while JobControl takes `mapred.Mapper`. (am I right on this part?)

Now my question is: should I keep using [mapreduce.Mapper](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.html) and give up [JobControl](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/jobcontrol/JobControl.html) and find something else to connect my jobs, or change my implementation to [mapred.Mapper](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/Mapper.html) and keep using `JobControl`.  Is one of them considered depreciated?

Comment: Is `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper` a typo?

Comment: @Paul Bellora: No, it seems that hadoop has two versions of Mapper.  One is under `mapred`, and the other from `mapreduce`.

Comment: I am still working on this problem, but I am wondering which change makes more sense: either using `JobControl` and re-write my Mapper to implement `mapred.Mapper`, or keep using `mapreduce.Mapper` and give up `JobControl`.

Comment: Related: [hadoop.mapred vs hadoop.mapreduce?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269922/hadoop-mapred-vs-hadoop-mapreduce)

Comment: Thank you, Paul! I am now trying to throw away the `JobControl`, which is based on `mapred` library, and finding better way to connect jobs :~~.

Comment: Well I found this class when searching: [`org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.JobControl`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jobcontrol/JobControl.html) Is that the answer? I don't quite get the `JobConf` connection (no Hadoop experience).

Comment: Wow, that might be the answer! I was using `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobcontrol.Jobcontrol` and didn't know the one you found!

Comment: Now I have tons of compile errors to fix.  I will later come back and post after I changed to mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.JobControl.  Thank you !!

Comment: Glad to help! I'll go ahead and put that in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the `mapred` and `mapreduce` packages are distinct from each other, with `mapreduce` being the newer, cleaner one. The differences are further discussed on this post: [hadoop.mapred vs hadoop.mapreduce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269922/hadoop-mapred-vs-hadoop-mapreduce)

So for your particular issue, it seems like you want to use [`org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.JobControl`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jobcontrol/JobControl.html) instead of [`org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobcontrol.JobControl`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/jobcontrol/JobControl.html).

See also: [Is it better to use the mapred or the mapreduce package to create a Hadoop Job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598422/is-it-better-to-use-the-mapred-or-the-mapreduce-package-to-create-a-hadoop-job)