# Error while using "newAPIHadoopFile" API

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am writing the following code to load a file into Spark using `newAPIHadoopFile` API.

```
val lines = sc.newAPIHadoopFile("new_actress.list",classOf[TextInputFormat],classOf[Text],classOf[Text])
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
scala> val lines = sc.newAPIHadoopFile("new_actress.list",classOf[TextInputFormat],classOf[Text],classOf[Text])
<console>:34: error: inferred type arguments [org.apache.hadoop.io.Text,org.apache.hadoop.io.Text,org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat] do not conform to method newAPIHadoopFile's type parameter bounds [K,V,F <: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat[K,V]]
 val lines = sc.newAPIHadoopFile("new_actress.list",classOf[TextInputFormat],classOf[Text],classOf[Text])
                ^
<console>:34: error: type mismatch;
found   : Class[org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat](classOf[org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat])
required: Class[F]
val lines = sc.newAPIHadoopFile("new_actress.list",classOf[TextInputFormat],classOf[Text],classOf[Text])
                                                          ^
<console>:34: error: type mismatch;
found   : Class[org.apache.hadoop.io.Text](classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.Text])
required: Class[K]
val lines = sc.newAPIHadoopFile("new_actress.list",classOf[TextInputFormat],classOf[Text],classOf[Text])
                                                                                   ^
<console>:34: error: type mismatch;
found   : Class[org.apache.hadoop.io.Text](classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.Text])
required: Class[V]
val lines = sc.newAPIHadoopFile("new_actress.list",classOf[TextInputFormat],classOf[Text],classOf[Text])
                                                                                                 ^
```

What am I doing wrong in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`TextInputFormat`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/TextInputFormat.html) takes `<LongWritable,Text>`.

**Note:** be focused on extends part in both `**InputFormat`

```
@InterfaceAudience.Public
@InterfaceStability.Stable
public class TextInputFormat
extends FileInputFormat<LongWritable,Text>
```

that means you can not set both types for `FileInputFormat` as `Text`. If you want to use `FileInputFormat` you need to do something like:

**You can try:**

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
val lines = sc.newAPIHadoopFile("test.csv", classOf[TextInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text])
```

but in case you still want to use **both types as `Text`** you can use [`KeyValueTextInputFormat`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/KeyValueTextInputFormat.html) which is defined as:

```
@InterfaceAudience.Public @InterfaceStability.Stable public class
KeyValueTextInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<Text,Text>
```

**You can try:**

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.KeyValueTextInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
val lines = sc.newAPIHadoopFile("test.csv", classOf[KeyValueTextInputFormat], classOf[Text], classOf[Text])
```

Comment: Thanks...one more thing, is there any difference between `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat` and `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat`? Which one should be chosen?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269922/hadoop-mapred-vs-hadoop-mapreduce