# Hadoop NEW API enabled by default

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

Hadoop old API is deprecated for some time now, and there is not much information about the new one (I'm not talking about YARN, but about the http://hadoopbeforestarting.blogspot.com/2012/12/difference-between-hadoop-old-api-and.html). I searched for days how could I enable it by default? Only solutions I've seen so far is setting configurations in `oozie workflow.xml` or setting `JobConf.setUseNewMapper(true)` and `JobConf.setUseNewReducer(true)` inside own mapreduce. So my question is: how can I enable it by default, so every single job would use it? I mean Hive, HBase and etc. generated jobs. I tried setting `mapred.mapper.new-api` and `mapred.mapper.new-api` to true in `mapred-site.xml` but it doesn't work.

Moreover I found deprecated settings: http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/hadoop/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/DeprecatedProperties.html . I think new properties only works on new api, because after setting `mapreduce.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum` and `mapreduce.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum` in `mapred-site.xml` to other than the default value, I still get default value (2). And if I set deprecated properties - `mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum` and `mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum` it works like a charm.

Comment: You can't force it, but it is undeprecated in newer hadoop versions anyway- so nothing to really bother about.

Comment: If this is really the case - you should post answer and I'll accept it. Also, could you post any links to any article or hadoop announcement about this?

Comment: Just go with Praveen's answer here (you can upvote and we can close this as a duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598422/is-it-better-to-use-the-mapred-or-the-mapreduce-package-to-create-a-hadoop-job?rq=1