# MapReduceBase and Mapper deprecated

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

```
public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper
```

`MapReduceBase`, `Mapper` and `JobConf` are deprecated in *Hadoop 0.20.203*.

What should we use now?

Edit 1 - for the `Mapper` and the `MapReduceBase`, I found that we just need to extends the `Mapper`

```
public static class Map extends Mapper
            <LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
  private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
  private Text word = new Text();

  public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, 
         OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, 
         Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
    String line = value.toString();
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
      word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
      output.collect(word, one);
    }
  }
}
```

Edit 2 - For `JobConf` we should use configuration like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = new Job(conf);
        job.setMapperClass(WordCount.Map.class);
    }
```

Edit 3 - I found a good tutorial according to the new API : http://sonerbalkir.blogspot.com/2010/01/new-hadoop-api-020x.html

Comment: What does the documentation say you should use?  Usually, when something is deprecated the Javadoc will say what you should use instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Javadoc contains info what to use instaed of this depraceated classes:

e.g. http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.html

```
 Deprecated. Use Configuration instead
```

Edit: When you use maven and open class declaration (F3) maven can automatically download source code and you'll see content of javadoc comments with explanations.

Comment: + 1 for the Configuration. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There is not much different [functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598422/is-it-better-to-use-the-mapred-or-the-mapreduce-package-to-create-a-hadoop-job/) wise between the old and the new API, except that the old API supports push to the map/reduce functions, while the new API supports [both push and pull API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537797/how-to-pull-data-in-the-map-reduce-functions). Although, the new API is much cleaner and easy to evolve.

Here is the [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-1230) for the introduction of the new API. Also, the old API has been [un-deprecated](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-1735) in 0.21 and will be deprecated in [release 0.22 or 0.23](http://www.mail-archive.com/mapreduce-user@hadoop.apache.org/msg03353.html).

You can find more information about the new API or sometimes called the 'context objects' [here](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2009/05/what%E2%80%99s-new-in-hadoop-core-020/) and [here](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2010/08/what%E2%80%99s-new-in-apache-hadoop-0-21/).