# Hadoop: What to use instead of deprecated interfaces Mapper and Reducer?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, version, deprecated

I'm using Hadoop version 0.22.0 downloaded [here](http://apache.miloslavbrada.cz/hadoop/common/hadoop-0.22.0/hadoop-0.22.0.tar.gz). I started to create my custom mapper and reducer according to [this](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/DOC/Hadoop+Tutorial) tutorial and found out that interface `Mapper<K1, V1, K2, V2>` that is to be implemented by all mapper classes is deprecated. Interface `Reducer<K2, V2, K3, V3>` that is meant to be implemented by all reducers (at least according to [the tutorial](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/DOC/Hadoop+Tutorial)) is also deprecated. So are classes like `MapReduceBase` and `JobConf`. These are all core classes and interfaces that are needed by all custom mappers and reducers, aren't they? There is no note in javadoc what should be used as a replacement of those deprecated classes.

So what interfaces and classes should I use instead of those deprecated ones? Or should I use them anyway? Why are they deprecated? Please just explain to me what's going on and what should I do because I'm not getting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a class (not interface!) with the same name `Mapper<KEYIN, VALUEIN, KEYOUT, VALUEOUT>` in package `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce` that should be used instead of the interface and base class. Same story with reducer: there is a class `Reducer<KEYIN, VALUEIN, KEYOUT, VALUEOUT>` in package `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce`.

I still don't know what to do with `JobConf` and such but I'll update my answer when I found out.

---

Edit: Class `Configuration` is to be used instead of `JobConf`.

Answer (score 1):

Classes from the [org.apache.hadoop.mapred](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/mapreduce/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/package-frame.html) package are from the old MR API and from the [org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/mapreduce/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/package-frame.html) are from the new API. Note that all the classes have not been ported from the old API to the new API. Here is a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626077/mapreducebase-and-mapper-deprecated/7627822#7627822) thread from SO.