# Why am I not getting the ouput written in output files in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, distributed-computing

I have written the following code to find the maximum temperature but when I am trying to retrieve the output, the files are created but are empty. I don't really understand why is this happening...Can someone please just help?

***My runner code:***

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat;

public class MaxTemp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JobConf conf = new JobConf(MaxTemp.class);
        conf.setJobName("MaxTemp1");
        conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
        conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
        conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        conf.setMapperClass(MaxTempMapper.class);
        conf.setCombinerClass(MaxTempReducer.class);
        conf.setReducerClass(MaxTempReducer.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf,new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf,new Path(args[1]));
        JobClient.runJob(conf);
    }
}
```

****Mapper code:****

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;

public class MaxTempMapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,IntWritable> {
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text,IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        String record = value.toString();
        String[] parts = record.split(",");
        output.collect(new Text(parts[0]), new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(parts[1])));
    }
}
```

**My reducer code:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;

public class MaxTempReducer extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
    public void reduce1(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text,IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        int maxValue = 0;
        while (values.hasNext()) {
            maxValue=Math.max(maxValue,values.next().get());
        }
        output.collect(key, new IntWritable(maxValue));
    }


    @Override
    public void reduce(Text arg0, Iterator<IntWritable> arg1, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> arg2, Reporter arg3) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    }
}
```

I am attaching the output screenshots
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't help but notice that inside the `MaxTempReducer` class you have the `reduce1` function, while overriding the proper `reduce` function to be used *outside* of the class of the reducer. This is the reason you don't get any output in the *HDFS*, because the program sees the reducer class, but doesn't see the `reduce` function that describes what you want to do with it (aka find the max of the temperature).

There's also the issue that you are using [deprecated classes from old versions of Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626077/mapreducebase-and-mapper-deprecated),  which can bear their own issues as the framework and its components are getting tested updated on a satisfactory basis (as you can check by yourself over [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/)).

So by fixing those two issues, your program could look a bit like this:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Counters;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class MaxTemp 
{
    /* input:  <byte_offset, line_of_dataset>
     * output: <City, Temperature>
     */
    public static class Map extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> 
    {
        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
        {
            String record = value.toString();
            String[] parts = record.split(", ");

            context.write(new Text(parts[0]), new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(parts[1])));
        }
    }

    /* input:  <City, Temperature>
     * output: <City, Max Temperature>
     */
    public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>
    {
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
        {
            int max_value = 0;
            
            for(IntWritable value : values)
            {
                if(value.get() > max_value)
                    max_value = value.get();
            }

            context.write(key, new IntWritable(max_value));
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        // set the paths of the input and output directories in the HDFS
        Path input_dir = new Path("temperatures");
        Path output_dir = new Path("temp_out");

        // in case the output directory already exists, delete it
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        if(fs.exists(output_dir))
            fs.delete(output_dir, true);

        // configure the MapReduce job
        Job maxtemp_job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Max Temperature");
        maxtemp_job.setJarByClass(MaxTemp.class);
        maxtemp_job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        maxtemp_job.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
        maxtemp_job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);    
        maxtemp_job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        maxtemp_job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        maxtemp_job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        maxtemp_job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(maxtemp_job, input_dir);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(maxtemp_job, output_dir);
        maxtemp_job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }
}
```

Where the `temperatures` directory in the HDFS looks like this:

```
Boston, 3
Athens, 15
Tokyo, 20
Tokyo, 10
Athens, 32
Boston, 9
```

And the results in the `temp_out` directory look like this (image from the HDFS browser of Hadoop):
[image]