# Which map reduce package to use

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

i see the map/reduce class present @ both org.apache.hadoop.mapred & org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce. What should we use and which is better?
I see org.apache.hadoop.mapred had been removed once but has been added back/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.apache.hadoop.mapred` is the package from legacy hadoop code. `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce` is the new addition from Hadoop 0.20.x.

Functionality wise there is not much difference between the old the new API. The only significant difference is that records are pushed to the mapper/reducer in the old API. While the new API supports both pull/push mechanism. You can get more information about the pull mechanism [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537797/how-to-pull-data-in-the-map-reduce-functions).

Also, the old API is deprecated. You can find more information about the new API [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2010/08/what%E2%80%99s-new-in-apache-hadoop-0-21/). Note that not all things are migrated from `mapred` to `mapreduce`. As far as possible, try to use the new API.

Comment: The old API won't be removed anymore, it will also be undeprecated sooner or later (if it isn't already in 2.0.x).

Comment: @ThomasJungblut thanks for the correction. updated my answer above.